# need to create binding and pass parameter in code behind

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I need to pass a parameter to a binded command of a menuitem.click
the menu items are created dynamically in code behind, how can i create binding and a commandparameter in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: [Binding Declarations Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx).

Basically you create an instance of `Binding` type and then assign it to an object via `BindingOperations.SetBinding()` method.